# Swift3 Submit POST form Behind POST login

Tags: ios, python-3.x, post, swift3

I've been trying to make a simple app to open an RFID door I have at my work. It is a pretty simplistic website, a POST login (With username, and pwd) and then another POST form that submits which door to open. So I created a script in Python3 that works perfectly to do it:

```
import requests
import collections

payload = collections.OrderedDict()
payload['username'] = 'admin'
payload['pwd'] = 'password'
payload['logId'] = '20101222'  

payload2 = collections.OrderedDict()
payload2['UNCLOSE1'] = 'Remote Open #1 Door Front Door'

payload3 = collections.OrderedDict()
payload3['s6'] = 'Exit'

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('http://192.168.99.25/ACT_ID_1', data=payload)
    print(p.text)
    print()

    r = s.post('http://192.168.99.25/ACT_ID_701', data=payload2)
    print(r.text)
    print()

    r2 = s.post('http://192.168.99.25/ACT_ID_21', data=payload3)
    print(r2.text)
```

So thats my Code in Python3, now I've been trying to port that over to swift3 (it would be easier for me within an app, unless there is an acceptable way to just run the python file)

I've been using URLSession but i just don't have the experience with it yet. if you want the code I've been trying to use i can post it, but its pretty rubbish.

thanks, -Asher

Edit:

Code i've been trying:

```
func connectToRFID(_ session: URLSession) {

    let addressOne = URL(string: "http://192.168.99.25/ACT_ID_1")!
    let postOne = "username=admin&pwd=password&logId=20101222"

    var request = URLRequest(url: addressOne)


    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postOne.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error = \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
        print()
    }
    task.resume()

func openRFID(_ session: URLSession) {
    let addressTwo = URL(string: "http://192.168.99.25/ACT_ID_701")!
    let postTwo = "UNCLOSE1=Remote Open #1 Door Front Door"
    var request2 = URLRequest(url: addressTwo)

    request2.httpMethod = "POST"
    request2.httpBody = postTwo.data(using: .utf8)

    let task2 = session.dataTask(with: request2) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error = \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")

    }
    task2.resume()
}

@IBAction func buttonPress(_ sender: Any) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    connectToRFID(session)
    print("One")
    openRFID(session)
}
```

I've also looked at several other posts, but most of them only tell me how to submit a POST. Btw, the `connectToRFID` function does login, (it responds the page behind the login), but the `openRFID` returns nothing in the console.

Comment: You should first make a research about the problem and try it first then come here ask about your problem, post the related code base, tell details about it etc. You can't get help like these.

Comment: @UlasSancak There I've added the Swift3 code, i apologise for not being more specific. i have research the problem, but none of the posts i am finding are helping me (yes I've tried combining solutions together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLSession tasks work asynchronously. So you can't call them line by line in the main thread. You need to wait the response. In your case:

After the login task is completed you need to call openRFID function.

```
func connectToRFID(_ session: URLSession) {

    let addressOne = URL(string: "http://192.168.99.25/ACT_ID_1")!
    let postOne = "username=admin&pwd=password&logId=20101222"

    var request = URLRequest(url: addressOne)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postOne.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error = \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }
        else {
            self.openRFID(URLSession.shared)
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            print()
        }
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
        print()
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try this in just a little while, I'm eating lunch. But that makes total sense, URLSession opens up a new "thread" (Python terms) and continues on in the code, basically.... I guess, that's how I'll think of it, thanks

Comment: You are welcome. In fact as soon as I saw it, I let you know. I don't know if there are any other problems. If there are, please let me know. And remember something as well. The response block is on the main thread, if you want to display some data based on the response data you should manually call the UI elements on the main thread using DispatchQueue.main.async {//Call UI elements}

Comment: works like an absolute charm, thank you so much! i actually jump when i heard the door open, lol.

Comment: I'm glad to help. :)